# JSONObjectRequest can't fill object with data

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to fill an object with a data I read from a JSON url.

```
    public JSONHandler(final ImageButton canli, final ImageButton indie, final ImageButton easy, final ImageButton karisik, final ImageButton rock) {
    request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        channelObject = response.getJSONObject("channel0");
                        song = channelObject.getString("song");
                        artist = channelObject.getString("artist");
                        duration = channelObject.getInt("duration");
                        playedAt = channelObject.getInt("playedat");
                        channelImg = channelObject.getString("image_extralarge");
                        channel0 = new Channel(song, artist, duration, playedAt, channelImg);
                        Picasso.get().load(channel1.getImg()).fit().into(indie);
```

I'm using this structure for filling ImageButton and other things. As you can see I can only fill the buttons etc. inside my method. Is it a way to take the channel1 object in my method and save it for use situations later?

Answer (score 0):

You can save every field to sharedPreference or you can :

Add this to gradle file,

> implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

**To put data:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String res = gson.toJson(channel0);
editor.putString("data", res);
editor.apply();
```

**To get data :**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = prefs.getString("data", "");
Channel obj = gson.fromJson(data, Channel.class);
```

Comment: What is 'pref' ?

Comment: `pref` is `Shared Preferences`. Look into this doc for more details https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences